# Laravel ClamAV scanner client failed with error "Socket operation failed: Connection refused

Tags: laravel, macos, sockets, centos, clamav

I have created a validation system to check if the uploaded files are secured and virus-free, I'm using ClamAV for that purpose.

At first I was testing locally on my MACOS using XAMPP but I kept getting the below error

> Sunspikes \ ClamavValidator \ ClamavValidatorException ClamAV scanner
> client failed with error "Socket operation failed: Connection refused
> (SOCKET_ECONNREFUSED)" Previous exceptions Socket operation failed:
> Connection refused (SOCKET_ECONNREFUSED) (61)

I've uploaded the files to my cPanel/CentOS server thought that clamav is limited on MacOS unlike CentOS however I got the same error.

The code used as follow:

```
public function upload(KycUploadRequest $request) {

    $this->validate($request, [
        'address' => 'clamav',
        'document' => 'clamav'
        ]
    );
   //
    $user = Auth::user();

    $data = $request->all();

    if($file = $request->file('address')) {
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('images', $name);
        $data['address'] = $name;
    }
    if($file2 = $request->file('document')) {
        $name = time() . $file2->getClientOriginalName();
        $file2->move('images', $name);
        $data['document'] = $name;
    }

    $kyc = new KycVerification();
    $kyc->user_id = $user->id;
    $kyc->address = $data['address'];
    $kyc->document = $data['document'];
    $kyc->status = 1;
    $kyc->save();

    Session::flash('status', 'Your documents were sent for verification, you will receive a notification status about your request!');
    return redirect()->back();

}
```

I use this package: https://github.com/sunspikes/clamav-validator

I'm stuck for hours with no solution, any help please. Note I'm using laravel 5.8 both on xampp/macos and cpanel/centos.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a required server running.

Comment: on cPanel it's installed as a 3rd party module coming with cPanel. Locally on my MACOS I've ran "clamd" and shows it's working especially in the Activity Monitor